# Linux Wordpress can't write wp-config file

Tags: permissions, wordpress

I installed the latest version of Apache2 / PHP / MYSQL on my PC.

In the directory `/src/www/htdocs` I created a directory `wordpress` with all wordpress files.

Then, when I tried to create the `wp-config` file through the web interface I get this error:

```
Sorry, but I can't write the `wp-config.php' file.
```

I tried this command to change the group of `/src/www/htdocs/wordpress`

```
chown -R root:root /srv/www/htdocs/wordpress
```

But it was not working. After some research, I have seen lot of people saying change the group to `www-data` but I do not see `www-data` using this command:

```
cut -d: -f1 /etc/group
```

Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: The user and group that apache run as is set in `/etc/apache2/envvars` on my debian system.

Comment: Look to see who wordpress/apache is running as. On my system it is `www-data`, I would then have to make sure the files that it needs to change were owned by it (`www-data`).

Comment: Changing owner and group to root can never increase permissions, as root already has permission.

Comment: Try:
chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/

Answer (score 5):

Just change the own of the folder from root to your current user.

```
sudo chown -R yourcurrentuser:currentgroup /srv/www/htdocs/wordpress
```

Answer (score 4):

If `wp-config.php` doesn't exist yet, use:

```
cp wp-config-sample.php wp-config.php
```

The group that apache uses is in an Apache config file. Here's how I find in on OS X. for me, the group is `_www`:

```
grep ^Group /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
```

There are 3 permissions groups that Unix/Linux uses - `user`, `group`, `others`. I'm assuming you'll want to remain the `user` that owns the file. The easiest thing to do is give write permission to the `group` and `others`. To do that, use:

```
 chmod go+w wp-config.php
```

Answer (score 3):

First, find out which group the Apache daemon is currently using:

```
$ cat /etc/apache2/apache2.conf | grep ^Group -B 2
# These need to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}
```

OK. This means the group is stored in the `APACHE_RUN_GROUP` variable:

```
$ echo ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}
```

That variable isn't set in the current environment. Why? I don't really know. But it doesn't matter, because the comment in the Apache config file points us to the file where these variables are defined:

```
$ cat /etc/apache2/envvars | grep GROUP
export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=www-data
```

So in my case, the group Apache is running under is `www-data`. With this info, now change the group of the WordPress directory. In your case:

```
sudo chgrp -R www-data /src/www/htdocs
```

The `-R` flag makes it recursive. Et voilà!

Answer (score 1):

My own way:
1. Open Xampp

2. Open Xampp application folder
3. In search bar: Search file wp-config-sample.php
4. Rename it to wp-config.php
5. Open it by Text Editor
6. Replace all exsited content by Code gave by Wordpress as comment above.

Answer (score 1):

For nginx users, the default user is `www-data`, so we need to grant write permissions to the `www-data` user:

```bsh
chown -R www-data wordpress
```

Answer (score 0):

Manually create `wp-config.php` file and past the code which looks like this and re-install the same it will work.

```
<?php
/**
 * The base configuration for WordPress
 *
 * The wp-config.php creation script uses this file during the
 * installation. You don't have to use the web site, you can
 * copy this file to "wp-config.php" and fill in the values.
 *
 * This file contains the following configurations:
 *
 * * MySQL settings
 * * Secret keys
 * * Database table prefix
 * * ABSPATH
 *
 * @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

// ** MySQL settings - You can get this info from your web host ** //
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define('DB_NAME', 'landdb');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'root');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

/** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8mb4');

/** The Database Collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
define('DB_COLLATE', '');

/**#@+
 * Authentication Unique Keys and Salts.
 *
 * Change these to different unique phrases!
 * You can generate these using the {@link https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/ WordPress.org secret-key service}
 * You can change these at any point in time to invalidate all existing cookies. This will force all users to have to log in again.
 *
 * @since 2.6.0
 */
define('AUTH_KEY',         '>-QGUoR0nVWO9 rl=XOk}/yn[sZf=[HcZk8@J6Icm/:p#z+4jmJF]n~6m2y?n,TV');
define('SECURE_AUTH_KEY',  '0Sq%,SJ5KP|]wvufKIfn0s4}.=Ln]UuPF8k<Zo]X{]7^4;VT5}q%UITl,!{7w2QM');
define('LOGGED_IN_KEY',    'A[sS*[{ksr}2!qf8G`=&3Z)=vOJGd%X|7k=49s9BZ7k|n7j_WhHPGw*SP.o{?W`#');
define('NONCE_KEY',        '71{xg#3i$Q)L aybW9KPvsRZ&PaV#[[Lc# # 6Q<Mk*7Pi6W(Qh`t$^s>/S:aT>z');
define('AUTH_SALT',        'qa-S$)X)-C(&~:TPD~WQlX,q788*NBCN_:3jGmr@X|@iAOAZ`~igO3>)Z+L[xQQr');
define('SECURE_AUTH_SALT', 'mXE7Glb~H)O<GgB{XMJ.e|~=/t<z~mIQY.Dt=_b)IlUX=$qx@/]w<]bHt1?H(a7 ');
define('LOGGED_IN_SALT',   '=0T`7(nbT&n`%eOx0[fk%)v_ncoZf +Br&<Wi3N> Vy0XD/)w8?3xw2c9LOKlSR-');
define('NONCE_SALT',       'rvK~}( 5kjw4Wd<vgFLu5eCp%n03 e-&;5mL5J,aQ.M*RY{7n8GtoN}0aj-jzXC<');

/**#@-*/

/**
 * WordPress Database Table prefix.
 *
 * You can have multiple installations in one database if you give each
 * a unique prefix. Only numbers, letters, and underscores please!
 */
$table_prefix  = 'wp_';

/**
 * For developers: WordPress debugging mode.
 *
 * Change this to true to enable the display of notices during development.
 * It is strongly recommended that plugin and theme developers use WP_DEBUG
 * in their development environments.
 *
 * For information on other constants that can be used for debugging,
 * visit the Codex.
 *
 * @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress
 */
define('WP_DEBUG', false);

/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */

/** Absolute path to the WordPress directory. */
if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
    define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');

/** Sets up WordPress vars and included files. */
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');
```